# How i can call more than one Api in different Activity using volley?

Tags: android, xml, android-volley

**how can i use two url or api to get fetch data in diffeternt actvity using volley in single project?**

Comment: You can put however many urls you want into one or more activities... That is not a limitation... Just make a new VolleyQueue in the other activity and use it for whatever url value... I don't understand your question

Comment: can you give me some example or video please

Comment: Asking for off-site resources is off-topic for StackOverflow. First, Volley doesn't care about XML. Second, have you *tried* to make another `Volley.newRequestQueue(this);` in the other Activty?

Comment: Also, if you are parsing JSON and want to separate the networking methods away from Activity classes, you should look into Retrofit instead of Volley